# Ionic Product of Water

Tags: equilibrium, water

Why is the ionic product for water ($K_\text{w}$) temperature dependent? The concentration of $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ ions in pure water is $[\ce{H+}] = [\ce{OH-}] = 1.0\times 10^{-7}\ \mathrm{mol/l}$ at $25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$, and therefore the ionic product of water at $25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ is $1.0\times 10^{-14}$. Why it is so? What is the effect of temperature on this value?

Comment: Equilibrium constants are related to free energy and free energy is [strongly dependent on temperature](http://www.chem.ufl.edu/~itl/2045/lectures/lec_v.html).

Comment: Wikipedia has [some useful graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water#Dependence_on_temperature.2C_pressure_and_ionic_strength) regarding the dependence of the ionic product of water on temperature, pressure and amount of dissolved ions.

Answer (score 4):

I think [this link](http://www.chem.ufl.edu/~itl/2045/lectures/lec_v.html) should really help you out in understanding how the equilibrium constant depends on temperature.

Now, considering the case of water dissociation:
$$\ce{H2O <=> H+ + HO-}$$

We can calculate the free energy of the reaction ($\Delta_\text{r}G$), using the Gibbs energy for the reactant and the products (in aqueous solution):

$$\Delta G(\ce{H2O}) = -237.13\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$$
$$\Delta G(\ce{H+}) = 0\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$$
$$\Delta G(\ce{HO-}) = -157.24\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$$

$$\Delta_\text{r}G = \Delta G(\ce{H+}) + \Delta G(\ce{HO-}) - \Delta G(\ce{H2O}) = -157.24\ \mathrm{kJ/mol} + 237.13\ \mathrm{kJ/mol} = 79.89\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$$
The values of the Gibbs energies were taken from the 8th edition of Atkins' Physical Chemistry.
Now, applying the formula below (which can be obtained from $\Delta_\text{r}G = -RT\ln K_\text{eq}$) for $T = 298\ \mathrm{K}$ (or $25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$):
$$K_\text{eq} = \operatorname{e}^{-\frac{\Delta_\text{r}G}{RT}}$$
we get something like this : 
$$K_\text{eq} = 2.71^{-\frac{79890\ \mathrm{J\ mol^{-1}}}{8.3145\ \mathrm{J\ mol^{-1}\ K^{-1}} \times 298\ \mathrm{K}}} = 9.93 \times 10^{-15}$$
This value can be approximated to ${10^{-14}}$.

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach would be that

> concentration of hydromium and hydroxyl ions will increase with
>   temperature

as tendency of

> water to dissociate will increase

Hence, more quantity of products means greater Ionic Product.

Comment: This is much oversimplified.  The Wikipedia graphs referred to in Nicolau's comment shows a maximum at constant pressure, beyond which the ion product drops.  Decreasing density, which kills the hydrogen bonding, eventually overrides the temperature effect we would normally expect.